# Why the time RSA encryption and decryption depends on the key size and not the input length?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I read some white paper about RSA encryption. I find this statement. but I  can't understood why?
Statment is The time for RSA encryption and Decryption depends on the key size, but does not depend on the size and content of input data, if this statment right meaningly wehen encrypt 1000 byte , 10000 byte same time for encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: Normally you don't encrypt more than ~100 bytes with RSA. You encrypt the actual data with fast encryption like AES, and then you encrypt the AES key with RSA. That way you only need one expensive RSA operation per message (or even connection in the case of TLS).

Comment: ok. but I want know about RSA when use key length 1024 or 2048 or 3072 bits for compare performance with them. How many bits should be input with each case.

Comment: The key size and the maximum input length are the same. That's the answer to your entire question.

Comment: @EJP The maximum input length is smaller than the key size, padding costs quite a bit, e.g. 41 bytes for OAEP with SHA-1.

Answer (score 5):

The time is always the same because the input length is always the same.

The plain text is padded to the size of the RSA modulus. If the plain text is too long, you cannot encrypt it with RSA. Of course, you can split your plain text up and encrypt each chunk with an independent RSA operation, but this isn't how the algorithm was intended to be used.

RSA encryption is best suited as a key transport algorithm. You choose a symmetric key, and use an RSA public key to encrypt it. The symmetric key can be used for encrypting a lot of data with some algorithm like AES. This is much, much faster than using public key cryptography to encrypt and decrypt bulk data.